# What are the restrictions on closed questions?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

Let's say A is somebody that asked a question.
B is somebody that gave an answer.
C is somebody that didn't.

The question gets closed.

Presumably, C cannot post an answer.

A can comment.

Can B or C comment?

Any other info on restrictions to "writing" to the closed question thread?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot post a new answer on a closed question. [That is about it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10582/what-is-a-closed-question).

Comment: I think you mean nobody can.